# How to trigger IonModal from an IonTabBar using Ionic React

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react

I have a specific use-case where I need to trigger a modal to open by clicking a tab from the tab bar. Similar to how Instagram triggers a modal to open when clicking the (+) icon in the tab bar to add a new post.

Given the following Ionic React tabs set up, how should I reconfigure to make this work? I would very much like to avoid having to copy/paste my modal code on to every single page.

**App.tsx**

```
const App: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <IonApp>
      <IonReactRouter>
        <IonTabs>
          <IonRouterOutlet>
            <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} exact={true} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact={true} />
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home" />
          </IonRouterOutlet>
          <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
            <IonTabButton tab="home" href="/home">
              <IonIcon icon={triangle} />
              <IonLabel>Explore</IonLabel>
            </IonTabButton>
            <IonTabButton tab="submit" href="/submit">
              <IonIcon icon={addCircle} />
              <IonLabel>Submit</IonLabel>
            </IonTabButton>
            <IonTabButton tab="login" href="/login">
              <IonIcon icon={square} />
              <IonLabel>Log In</IonLabel>
            </IonTabButton>
          </IonTabBar>
        </IonTabs>
      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>
  );
};
```

Where should I insert the following so that I can trigger this from the tab bar and have it overlay the page content regardless of what tab I am in?

```
<IonModal isOpen={showModal}>
     <p>This is modal content</p>
     <IonButton onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>Close Modal</IonButton>
</IonModal>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs

based on the tabs api you can determine which tab has been selected by the user and the call `setShowModal(true)`

Under Tab Events - https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs#events
There is an event called `tabSelected`

Comment: right, but where do I place the jsx to display the modal? As a sibling to `IonTabs`?

Comment: in what ever tabe you what the modal to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Since the modal does not need a route of its own, and `IonTabBar` can only accept `IonTabButton` as children, if you want to put an `IonButton` in there that opens the modal, it needs to be placed above `IonTabs` and absolute styling used to position it over the tab bar. You can place a dummy `IonTabButton` in the tab bar to ensure space is left for the absolutely-positioned button (making sure to visibly hide it with styling).

To get the modal to open by pressing the button, place your `IonModal` into its own component, and import it into App.tsx. Use the `trigger` prop on `IonModal` making sure to use the same `id` on the tab bar button as the `trigger` prop.

App.tsx

```
const App: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <IonApp>
      <IonButton fill="clear" id="open-modal">
        <IonIcon icon={addCircleOutline} />
      </IonButton>

      <MyModal />

      <IonReactRouter>
        <IonTabs>
          <IonRouterOutlet>
            <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} exact={true} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact={true} />
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home" />
          </IonRouterOutlet>
          <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
            <IonTabButton tab="home" href="/home">
              <IonIcon icon={triangle} />
              <IonLabel>Explore</IonLabel>
            </IonTabButton>
            <IonTabButton tab="submit" href="/submit">
              <IonIcon icon={addCircle} />
              <IonLabel>Submit</IonLabel>
            </IonTabButton>
            {/* Dummy button */}
            <IonTabButton />
            <IonTabButton tab="login" href="/login">
              <IonIcon icon={square} />
              <IonLabel>Log In</IonLabel>
            </IonTabButton>
          </IonTabBar>
        </IonTabs>
      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>
  );
};
```

MyModal.tsx

```
<IonModal isOpen={showModal} trigger="open-modal">
     <p>This is modal content</p>
     <IonButton onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>Close Modal</IonButton>
</IonModal>
```

It seems a very hacky solution. There should be a better way to achieve it.